# Frequent site in Office 365 are showing .aspx instead of Site Title Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Please help me out with this issue

I checked my Frequent sites and I see this issue.  Some of the sites have the site name, but some of them have the page name like below.  Do you know why that is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: This isn't something we can likely answer for you. This page is totally under control by Microsoft, I'd encourage you to submit a ticket at https://portal.office.com/support/support.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Please check Site collection Title and Description. It may come from there.

Comment: site collection title is Different it is not coming from there and thank you